# How to get attribute text where there is a colon in the tag

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML line:

```
<super:FirstName> Tom </super:FirstName>
```

And I want to get the value of the text between the tags i.e. I only want to get "Tom".

I have tried using:

```
//*[name()='super:FirstName'][text()]
```

However this is outputting the full XML line including the tags.

Any one have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Move `text()` out of the predicate:

```
//*[name()='super:FirstName']/text()
```

Or, if you're ignoring the namespace prefix:

```
//*[local-name()='FirstName']/text()
```

Or, if you're dealing with namespaces properly, register the prefix with your XPath library, and use this:

```
//super:FirstName/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

The colon introduces a namespace. In most programming languages, you have to register the namespace before you can use it in XPath. If you want to ignore it, use

```
 //*[local-name()='FirstName']
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, much appreciated! However I am still seeing the full XML line and not just "Tom"... do you know how I can get it to see just "Tom"?